# Which android class handles the text selection anchors in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a my own way of selecting because I want to select across multiple edittexts. And selection might include other Views also (not just text).

I have so far found that the `android.text.Selection` class handles text selecting. As this class is a static (constructor private) class it ensures that in the application there is no way to create 2 or more selections simultaneously (because when you add a new selection,it has to be done through this class and this class removes the previous selection when adding a new one). Therefore there is no way to select text in multiple edittexts at the same time.

So I'm trying to create my own way of selecting (yes, manually add a backgroundColorSpan when user does what is done when selecting).

But how do I deal with the anchors? As android is open source I'd like it if I can find the class that handles selection anchors (in other words the class which determines when to call `Selection` class to extend selections to the next line based on how user drags the anchor.) So in which class does this happen exactly?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested it's the,

`android.widget.Editor` class